# Is stack push and pop operation having more time complexity than linkedList removeFromLast and add operation?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack

when I solve a question in java language on LeetCode using stack operation(push and pop and peek) than the time complexity is 2888 ms. But when I replace stack to linkedList and (push(),pop()) to (add(),removeFromLast()) than the time complexity reduce to 188 ms. How?

Stack push() and pop() time compleixty is O(1) but after using linkedList operation how it give huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time complexity cannot be "2888 ms", because complexity isn't a measurement of absolute time. Time complexity only tells you how the runtime of an algorithm *scales* with input size. Now, different implementations can have the same complexity, but run at different (absolute) speeds. And even O(1) could be far slower than O(n) for small to medium inputs (but O(1) will always take the same time).

Java's `java.util.Stack` is a really old class and should not be used anymore. It builds on top of `Vector` and every single call to its methods is synchronized. That means for every method call, you need to perform a lock when calling the method and unlocking when leaving the method. This can add considerable runtime overhead.

A modern alternative to `Stack` is an `ArrayDeque`, which is even suggested by the [JavaDoc of `Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) itself:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example:
>
> ```
> Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
> ```